# Issues with opening files using Python

Tags: python, file

I am having trouble opening a .txt file using Python. Both my .txt file and script are in the same folder on my desktop, however I receive a "file not found" error when trying to open the file Random.txt. The file will open if I provide the complete path, which I am trying to avoid.

```
with open('Random.txt', 'r') as file:
    contents = file.read()
    print(contents)
```

I noticed that when I try the following code that it specifies that the file and script are in different directories.

```
import os



script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
file_path = 'Random.txt'
file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(file_path))

if script_dir == file_dir:
    print('The script and Random.txt file are in the same directory.')
else:
    print('The script and Random.txt file are in different directories.')

print()
print(script_dir)
print(file_dir)
```

Why am I receiving this error when trying to just use the file name (Random.txt) and not when using the complete path. When looking at the properties of both items in my folder they have the same path. I am using a Windows device, VSC, and Python 3.11.2

Comment: `open` with a relative path doesn't look in the folder your script is in. The path is relative to the current working directory, which is dependent on how you are running your script and might or might not align with the folder your script is in.

Comment: If you’re 110% sure the text file will always in the same directory as script:  `pa_txt = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / "Random.txt" ` will avoid current working directory issue.  When symlinks and home directories (posix) get involved , expanduser and resolve or absolute may be needed too.

Answer (score 0):

The sintax:

```
with open('Random.txt', 'r') as file:
```

will look for the file only look in the current working directory, which is not necessarily the same directory that the script is in. It is the most reasonable thing to do as searching in the whole computer would be too slow.

You must either put the file in the current working directory or use the relative path from this directory to the file, or use the absolute path.

Comment: _"will look for the file only in the same folder as the Python script."_ not quite, it'll look in the _current working directory_, which is not necessarily the same directory that the script is in